# Why do I need an Ubuntu One account for the Ubuntu Touch App store?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

While the usual tradition of linux distributions is to have repositories accessible to anyone, why do I need to have a ubuntu one account in order to download apps on the ubuntu store? While ubuntu has until now been very strong into providing open alternatives to mainline products, e.g. from microsoft or apple, this requirement is a serious threat to the open philosophy. I can't see any technical difficulty into not having accounts on the server side, and I am very worried about this.

Comment: You can safely create the account. There is no adverse net effect to 'open philosophy'.

Comment: @muru does your comment relate to the previous comment, or to my message?

Comment: It relates to your question.

Comment: Well, the proof is that when I use the emulator (ubuntu-emulator package in the repository), and when I try to download an app, it asks me to sign in. Is that what you are asking for? Otherwise I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Graham I'm not looking for an advice that it is safe, I'm looking for a real explanation. If I would need my identity card in order to buy some bread, and even if I trust my baker, would it be normal?

Comment: I do not need to log on to anything to install programmes on the phone I presently have. This is a very valid question.

Answer (score 1):

An Ubuntu One account is used for single sign on across all of the Ubuntu properties like Launchpad, the Software Center, Ask Ubuntu, the Forums, Discourse, etc so that you don't have to make multiple accounts on different sites.

Comment: I understand the 'it's practical' argument, however it should not be a requirement but only an option, especially in the app store, where you only 'pull' data from the server.

Comment: Does one detect a sense of mischief here?

Comment: I think it is really a serious concern. While you can use ubuntu without using the forums and all that, and therefore without having an account, the app store seems like something any user would really need. In that sense it is a real problem.

Comment: How is it a problem? You need a login so you can reinstall apps on your other computers, to leave a review, etc. All of the features of any app store need an identify provider.

Comment: What if I don't want to reinstall apps on my other computer nor leave a review? Indeed any other app store like google's or apple's do require an account, but I thought ubuntu was more attached to openness than these two! Offering the possibility to use an account and benefit from these features is ok, but requiring every user to have an account is a restriction on the user's freedom.

Comment: I don't see how "This is an account for all the Ubuntu stuff" answers the question "Why do I need this account?". I understand that you'd need an account for reviews and maybe syncing installed software (though in my opinion that's not a very useful thing as long as most my desktop programs aren't ported to Ubuntu Touch yet), but how does that justify making it mandatory even for downloading apps?